# is there a name for the itunes selection design pattern

Tags: design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UI: name of multiple column interface?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28693/ui-name-of-multiple-column-interface)

you know: with multiple select boxes arranged horizontally, with selection filtering from left to right....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it:  "[Column Browse](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/designing-web-interfaces-12-screen-patterns)"

Comment: Now that I have enough rep points to add comments, I can do this properly.... A tip, Sprugman: if you also mark your answer as "the" answer, then you'll get a badge for being a self-motivated learner (or something like that).

Answer (score 4):

Technically this is referring to an implementation of [Miller Columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_Columns), which is starting to become more popular with the rise of mobile applications (and thus, limited real-estate).

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at: [Cascading Lists at Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Search/ViewPattern%24pattern=Cascading+Lists).

Comment: Yes, Cascading Lists seems to be more appropriate. Check it out here too: http://designinginterfaces.com/Cascading_Lists